# select statement not retrieving all the rows in the database

Tags: java, sql

I have written a simple code to retrieve the values of a column from the table. The table contains about 220 something entries. When i run the program, it outputs the column's value after 118th entry. How to solve this problem. I want that the program should output all the values from 1st till the end.

```
  Connection con;

Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Airport","","");

           st= con.createStatement();

            String s1="Select * from Flight_Status1";

          rs=st.executeQuery(s1);

           while(rs.next())
           {

             System.out.println(rs.getInt(9));


        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: What happens after 118th entry, is there a crash, or does the program simply stop?

Comment: No, the code actually shows the values after the 118th entry and outputs these values till the end without any error.

Comment: Are you sure that column 9 (better write column name instead of 9) has not-null entries before 118.?

Comment: well, i have figured it out..Anyway, thanks for the help.. :)